# How to prove that Grandi's series $= \frac{1}{2}$ using Euler transform

Tags: real-analysis, summation, divergent-series

Let $x$ denote Grandi's series $1-1+1-1+1-1+1-...$

This implies that $$
x = 1\text{ or}\\
x = 0\text{ or}\\
1-x = 1 - (1-1+1-1+1-...) = x \implies 2x = 1 \implies x = \frac{1}{2}$$

Where the last sum seems counterintuitive as $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k =  \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{n}+1 \neq \frac{1}{2}$ but is proven by taking the Cesàro or Abel sum.

Is it possible to calculate in favour of $x=\frac{1}{2}$ by using [Euler transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html)?

Comment: After the first term in the Euler transform, everything else becomes zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to be more cautious about "*x*"; it's not clear what that letter is supposed to mean here. Anyway, yes, the Euler transform of the series $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ is $\frac12+0+0+\cdots$, which converges to $\frac12$. So the *Euler sum* of $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ is $\frac12$.

As [Euler himself](http://books.google.com/books?id=sYE_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA289&dq=%22Sit+igitur+proposita+haec+series+Leibnitzii%22) put it:

> I. *Sit igitur proposita haec series Leibnitzii:*
>   $$S=1-1+1-1+1-1+\mathrm{\&c.}$$
>   in qua cum omnes termini fint aequales, fient omnes differentiae $=0$, ideoque ob $a=1$, erit $S=\frac12$.

Comment: You are right $x=0$ or $x=1$ is $(1-1)+(1-1)+...$, or $1- (1+1)-(1+1)-...$ respectively...